# TukeyHSD or glht in R, ANCOVA

Tags: r, posthoc, tukey

I'm wondering if i can use the function "TukeyHSD" to perform the all pairwise comparisons of a "aov()" model with one factor (e.g., GROUP) and one continuous covariate (e.g., AGE). I did for example:

```
library(multcomp)
data('litter', package = 'multcomp')
litter.aov <- aov(weight ~ gesttime + dose, data = litter)
TukeyHSD(litter.aov, which = 'dose')
```

and i get a warning message like this:
Warning message:
In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf): non-factor ignored: gesttime

Is this process above correct? What's the meaning of the warning message? And does "TukeyHSD" apply to badly unbalanced designs?

In addition, is there any difference between the processes above and below?

```
litter.mc <- glht(litter.aov, linfct = mcp(dose = 'Tukey'))
summary(litter.mc)
```

Best, Sue

Comment: See the `?TukeyHSD` help page description: "...differences between the means of the _levels of a factor_ with the specified family-wise probability of coverage."

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference. `TukeyHSD()` is just a bit more eager to tell you about potential problems. Notice that it's a warning message, not an error, meaning that the results might not be what you expect, but they'll still be returned so you can judge for yourself.

As for what it means, it means what it says: non-factor variables are ignored. Remember that you are comparing the differences between groups, and grouping is done using factors, so factors are all `TukeyHSD()` care about. In your case you explicitly tell the function to only care about `dose`, which is factor, so the warning might be seen as overly cautious.

One way of avoiding the warning would be to convert `gesttime` into a factor, and as it consist of only four levels it makes some sense to do so.

```
data('litter', package = 'multcomp')
litter$gesttime <- as.factor(litter$gesttime)
litter.aov <- aov(weight ~ gesttime + dose, data = litter)

TukeyHSD(litter.aov, which = 'dose')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I'm not sure the existing answers are quite right...

I've been trying both functions with my own data and have a similar situation to Sue, where TukeyHSD gives a warning message about ignoring non-factor covariates, while glht() does not.

It does not appear that they are doing the same thing contrary to the other answer. The results are different and it appears that TukeyHSD is not marginalizing over the non-factor covariates (as the warning states). It appears that glht() correctly uses the mean value of non-factor covariates to compute the marginal mean of the groups of interest since the point estimates are the same as those obtained from lsmeans().

So it does not seem that TukeyHSD is overly cautious, it just seems that it can't handle non-factor covariates while glht is able to. So glht seems to be the correct function to use in this case, to me.